# Where's the old meta?

Tags: support, faq, meta, tea

Where's the old meta.mathoverflow.net?

Comment: Can user35287 accept the answer?

Comment: user35287 was a temporary user created while things weren't quite working perfectly a few minutes ago, and has since been deleted, so no, they can't accept the answer.

Answer (score 17):

It's now at [tea.mathoverflow.net](http://tea.mathoverflow.net)!

Comment: Furthermore, it always had the same little logo at the top of the web browser indicating a "tab," which I now realize was tea leaves all along.

Comment: Is *tea* an acronym, a pun, an abbreviation,  or something else?

Comment: It's in reference to all the math teas: https://www.google.com/search?q=math+department+tea

Comment: A new link to tea is http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/ - see [tea.mathoverflow.net deprecated](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3960).

Comment: For people who come to this question/answer searching for old tea discussions, I will add this link: [Tea archive (mathoverflow.tqft.net) seems to be down](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4438). (Some possible alternatives where to search can be found there.)