# What are the Frequently Asked Questions on meta?

Tags: support, faq, faq-proposed

Some questions on meta are tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). What does this mean?

I wanted to tag a questions [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) but it does not work and I wonder why and how I could get this tag on my question? Relatedly, what questions should be tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)?

Where can I find a list of all FAQs?

Answer (score 4):

**Some questions on meta are tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). What does this mean?**

The meta-tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) is a moderator-only tag, that is only a moderator can apply it to a question. Its purpose is to highlight some meta-question that seem particularly relevant in the long run; for short-term visibility there is a another tag [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).

These question can be "frequently asked" in a literal sense, but many also contain  information that just seems relevant to users or the site as a whole (see the list below to get an idea). They provide a natural extension of the Help Center, which is more static and in large parts not  editable  on a per-site basis. They also allow the community to be more directly involved in creating and curating the documentation of a site, which is particularly relevant for questions concerning policy and etiquette.

**How can a question be tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)?**

As mentioned at the start, the tag is a moderator-only tag, and it is this expected that  users  cannot directly apply it. A way to go about getting a question tagged as [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) is to apply the tag [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed). The proposal can then be reviewed by the community and the moderators. There is no hard and fast rule which questions should be tagged as [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). The existing list can provided some guidance. The list should stay reasonably short, so there should not be too many and a good case for adding a question, but it also makes sense to have important issues highlighted in this way. Also consider if expanding an existing FAQ, instead of adding a new one, could be an option.

A list of all questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) can be obtained by clicking on the tag-symbol (as for any tag). In addition, below there is a list of questions grouped by subject.

### List of (all) meta-questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), grouped by subject

**The site and its community as a whole**

- [History of MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/753/history-of-mathoverflow)
- [Best of MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow)
- [How is this site different from Mathematics Stack Exchange?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/271/how-is-this-site-different-from-mathematics-stack-exchange)

**Technical aspects, frequent support questions, the tag system, etc.**

- [How to write a good MathOverflow question?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/882/how-to-write-a-good-mathoverflow-question)
- [Best way to post graphics to MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1911/best-way-to-post-graphics-to-mo)
- [Frequently asked questions about tagging on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow)
- [How should I use the meta-tags [feature-request], [bug], [support], and [discussion]?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/439/how-should-i-use-the-meta-tags-feature-request-bug-support-and-discuss)
- [How to (re)tag such that migration works?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1429/how-to-retag-such-that-migration-works)

**Moderators and legal aspects**

- [Who owns MathOverflow?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/969/who-owns-mathoverflow)
- [Who owns my MathOverflow posts?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/950/who-owns-my-mathoverflow-posts)
- [Who are the MathOverflow moderators?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/833/who-are-the-mathoverflow-moderators)
- [What do moderators do?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/931/what-do-moderators-do)

**Community moderation and etiquette**

- [Editing etiquette](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2208/editing-etiquette)
- [What shall we do with stone soup?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1046/what-shall-we-do-with-stone-soup)

**Miscellanea**

- [Frequently Asked Questions: MathOverflow FAQ](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/203/frequently-asked-questions-mathoverflow-faq) (This is the pre-migration version; slightly updated at some places.)
- [Where's the old meta?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1/wheres-the-old-meta)