# Papers, articles, books and other resources discussing MathOverflow

Tags: discussion

There already is a post asking about published works which started on or were inspired by posts on MathOverflow: [Best of MathOverflow, or papers inspired by MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/617). It might be interesting to have some place to collect various resources which are *about MathOverflow*.

Also in connection with recent suggestion to discuss various possibilities [to study data about MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4113/studying-the-mathoverflow-data-dump-with-mathematica), it might be interesting to know about various papers that have already analysed some data about MO.

<sup>Originally I posted something similar to this as [an answer to History of MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/753/history-of-mathoverflow/755#755). After an advice from a moderator I have deleted it - I waited for some time, maybe it is reasonable to post it now. (Since the post is deleted, I will copy here the exchange in the comments under that answer: "I think this should be a separate question, as [discussed previously](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/563/where-to-share-mathoverflow-success-stories)." My response was: "I've understood Best of MathOverflow as a post for papers *based or inspired* by something from MO, not *about* MO." To wich I get the reply from the moderator: "Yes, as explained in the question I linked to, the best of is phase one of two.")</sup>

Comment: Some resources of this kind are also mentioned in the [Wikipedia article on MathOverflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathOverflow). (Some references in that article have been added relatively recently, probably in connection with the discussion whether MO is notable enough to have an article on WP: [Wikipedia:Articles for deletion/MathOverflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/MathOverflow).).

Answer (score 3):

## Papers and other resources analyzing data about MathOverflow

Let us collect here resources which analyze various aspects of MO.

- Montoya L.V., Ma A., Mondragón R.J. (2013) *Social Achievement and Centrality in MathOverflow.* https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-36844-8_3. This paper analyses mainly stuff related to users and interactions between them. It was referenced in Carlo Beenakker's answer to [On Mathematical Analysis of MathSciNet & MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/301299#301306) and also in another discussion here on meta: [Is MO connected?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1894#1896)
- Several papers by [Yla R. Tausczik](https://www.terpconnect.umd.edu/~ylatau/) with various coauthors. The first one was Yla Tausczik and James Pennebaker. 2011. *Predicting the Perceived Quality of Online Mathematics Contributions from Users' Reputations*. In *Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems*. ACM, pages 1885--1888; [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1978942.1979215), [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ylataus/files/TausczikPennebaker2011.pdf). There is a [thread on tea](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/890/mathoverflow-survey-update/) related to a survey of MO users. The survey was used in:
  Yla Tausczik and James Pennebaker. 2012.  *Participation in an online mathematics community: Differentiating motivations to add*.
  In *Proceedings of the ACM 2012 Conference on Computer Supported Cooperative Work*. ACM, pages 207-216; [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2145204.2145237), [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ylataus/files/TausczikPennebaker2012.pdf). There is also a website summarizing these two papers: http://www.utpsyc.org/MathOverflowSurvey/MathOverflowStudies.php. 
  There is also another MO related paper: Yla Tausczik, Aniket Kittur and Robert Kraut. 2014. *Collaborative problem solving: A study of Math Overflow*
  In *17th ACM Conference on Computer Supported Cooperative Work and Social Computing (CSCW 2014)* ACM, pages 355-367; [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2531602.2531690), [[PDF]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ylataus/files/TausczikKitturKraut2014.pdf) was mentioned in the question "[Statistics showing that more reputation for questions leads to better questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2202)" on meta.
- Ursula Martin, Alison Pease: *What does mathoverflow tell us about the production of mathematics?* https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0904. The authors study a sample of questions on MO, categorize them into various types and look at percentage answered. As Gerry Myerson pointed out, this paper is discussed in more detail in François G. Dorais' answer to [Is MO connected?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1894#1896)

Comment: This answer is [community wiki](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-wiki/info) - do not hesitate to edit it if you have some interesting additions.

Comment: The Montoya et al. paper is discussed at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1894/is-mo-connected

Comment: A related post about papers using data from the whole network or from some sites: [Academic papers using Stack Exchange data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134495).

Comment: This question on main is also (to some extent) related: [On Mathematical Analysis of MathSciNet & MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/301299).

Answer (score 2):

## Articles about MathOverflow

Let us collect here various resources which are about MathOverflow.

- [Announcement of the Math Overflow](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/math-overflow/) at Secret Blogging Seminar, October 2009. ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190210102727/https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/math-overflow/))
- Anton Geraschenko, Scott Morisson, Ravi Vakil: *Mathoverflow*, Notices of the AMS, June/July 2010, p. 701. [PDF](http://www.ams.org/notices/201006/rtx100600701p.pdf).

Comment: This answer is [community wiki](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-wiki/info) - do not hesitate to edit it if you have some interesting additions.

Comment: There is also a separate post which asks about [MO in the Notices of the AMS](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3154).